# How to copy a few faces from one bmesh to another

Tags: python, bmesh

I have a function that returns several faces from a mesh using ray_cast under the mouse pointer. Some surrounding faces are collected based on the angle from the hit face and passed to another function, most of this is done in `bmesh`.
In this function I want to copy the passed faces to a new bmesh to create a new object from them.

The best way I've found is to pass in the original bmesh with the faces I want to copy, iterate over it and append the new faces to a list:

```
def make_copy(self, context, bm_orig, faces_linked):
    # this gets called with bm_orig as the original bmesh in its entirety of type BMesh,  
    # and faces_linked as the faces of that bmesh that I want to copy to a new bmesh as a list of type BMFace
    
    bm_copy = bm_orig.copy()
    faces_linked_copy = []
    for face_orig in faces_linked:
        for face_copy in bm_copy.faces:
            if face_orig.index == face_copy.index:
                faces_linked_copy.append(face_copy)
    
    # then this makes a list of all the faces, checks them against the
    # list of faces I wan to keep (faces_linked_copy) and removes the rest from the list
    delete_list = []
    for face in bm_copy.faces:
        delete_list.append(face)
    
    for face_delete in bm_copy.faces:
        for face_save in faces_linked_copy:
            if face_delete == face_save:
                delete_list.remove(face_save)
    
    # finally using delete_list to remove all the faces I don't want
    bmesh.ops.delete(bm_copy, geom=delete_list, context="FACES")
```

From this I can delete all other faces in `bm_copy` and be left with the faces I need.
This works but it's **extremely slow** when operating on dense meshes.

This needs to happen every mouse move in a modal so with denser meshes this becomes unusable.

I've tried using `bmesh.ops.duplicate` with the `dest=bm_new` option but this always gives `keyword "dest" type 4 not working yet!` which it has done forever... (Am I doing something wrong with that?? or will they simply never implement it??)

**Question is:**
Is there a better way to copy some faces from one bmesh to another without having to copy and iterate over the original??

**EDIT**
@lemon since you were curious as to what this was for, it does this:
[image]

Collects the faces, then makes the blue faces from it.
But now seeing it work I probably wont use it this way 
But I have learned some things, so thanks again for your help

Comment: could you add more details or provide a test case? specially, if `face_copy.index` is lower than `len(bm_place.faces)`, you'll find the copy with `bm_plane.faces[face_orig.index]`.

Comment: @lemon I've updated the code in the question, hope this makes it clearer. There was a typo with `bm_plane.faces` as well. The main question: Is there a better way to copy some faces from one bmesh to another? A more built-in way? Or some way that doesn't require iterating over the enire mesh, as there could be 100K faces and this happens every mouse move in a modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts in this answer but I lake of context (so please use comments if not clear or not appropriated).

Your code optimisation, which mainly avoids loops and inner loops.

```
def make_copy(self, context, bm_orig, faces_linked):

    # creates a copy
    bm_copy = bm_orig.copy()

    # gets a set of face indices for fast access
    to_keep_indices = set(f.index for f in faces_linked)
    
    # creates the list of the faces to delete
    delete_list = [f for f in bm_copy.faces \
        if f.index not in to_keep_indices]
    
    # deletes
    bmesh.ops.delete(bm_copy, geom=delete_list, context="FACES")
    
    return bm_copy
```

A proposal that avoids to create a bmesh copy of a potential big bmesh.

```
def from_faces_linked(self, context, bm_orig, faces_linked):
    
    # set gets unique elements, list gets ordered elements    
    vertices = list(set(v for f in faces_linked for v in f.verts))

    # establishes a map between the new mesh vertex indices and 
    # actual mesh vertex indices
    vmap = dict()
    for i, vert in enumerate(vertices):
        vmap[vert.index] = i
    
    coordinates = [v.co for v in vertices]
    
    # build faces with new indices
    faces = []
    for face in faces_linked:
        faces.append([vmap[v.index] for v in face.verts])

    # create a mesh from that
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="copy")
    mesh.from_pydata(coordinates, [], faces)

    # and a bmesh from this mesh
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)
    
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)    

    return bm
```

Comment: Thanks a heap @lemon! That 2nd method is exactly what I was looking for! I'd tried to go down the `from_pydata` route but couldn't quite get it to work properly.... and it was far more complex than your version. You've taught me quite a lot today!

Comment: I've added a little video to my question with your working code as you wanted a use case for it. I miss a lot of tools from the CAD world so I'm trying to recreate them

Comment: @Psyonic, thanks a lot for this feedback. That seems to be a cool addon!

Comment: Thanks mate, and thanks again for your help. It's actually just fun to use 